# When using the JAVA addBatch() and executeBatch() I get error message

Tags: java

I'm trying to add line item data from a screen into the derby db table. The line items are in rows with 3 fields (columns).

I tried using `addBatch()` but get null errors. Without `addBatch()`, I get no errors. So I changed to the `executeUpdate()` approach. The problem is that now I get repetitive entries of the same thing (up to 2 pages worth) within the database. It also posts the empty line item rows into the database. I tried using if statements but the method just ignores them. Here's the code. What am I doing wrong? I use this software program for my daily work so I do need to get this resolved. Please.

```
public void updatePROPOSAL() throws SQLException{

    //Connection conn =null;
 //   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
   // DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

    String addSQL2 = "INSERT INTO MATERIALTBL (MATLINEITEM, 
    MATLINEITEMCOST, "
    + "MATLINEITEMQTY, MATMOSS, MATCRM)"
    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
       try { 



        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:proposaldb");

       int tubes = jtxtfld_TUBES.getText().length();
        System.out.println(tubes);
        if(tubes != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_TUBES.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_TUBES_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_TUBES_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
       }


       int coup = jtxtfld_COUP.getText().length();
        System.out.println(coup);
       if (coup != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_COUP.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_COUP_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_COUP_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
         }

        int cmtrs = jtxtfld_CMTRS.getText().length();
         System.out.println(cmtrs);
        if(cmtrs != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_CMTRS.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_CMTRS_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_CMTRS_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
       }

        int spaceone = jtxtfld_spaceONE.getText().length();
         System.out.println(spaceone);
       if (spaceone != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_spaceONE.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_spaceONE_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_spaceONE_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
       }

        int hmtrs = jtxtfld_HMTRS.getText().length();
         System.out.println(hmtrs);
        if (hmtrs != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_HMTRS.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_HMTRS_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_HMTRS_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
        }

        int spacetwo = jtxtfld_spaceTWO.getText().length();
         System.out.println(spacetwo);
        if(spacetwo != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_spaceTWO.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_spaceTWO_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_spaceTWO_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
        }

        int gmtrs = jtxtfld_GMTRS.getText().length();
         System.out.println(gmtrs);
        if (gmtrs != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_GMTRS.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_GMTRS_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_GMTRS_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
        }

        int spacethree = jtxtfld_spaceTHREE.getText().length();
         System.out.println(spacethree);
        if (spacethree != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_spaceTHREE.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_spaceTHREE_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_spaceTHREE_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
        }


        int emtrs = jtxtfld_EMTRS.getText().length();
         System.out.println(emtrs);
        if (emtrs != 0) {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_EMTRS.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jtxtfld_EMTRS_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_EMTRS_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
        }

        int spacefour = jtxtfld_spaceFOUR.getText().length();
         System.out.println(spacefour);
        if (spacefour != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_spaceFOUR.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jtxtfld_spaceFOUR_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_spaceFOUR_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
       }

       int count = jtxtfld_COUNT.getText().length();
        System.out.println(count);
       if (count != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_COUNT.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_COUNT_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_COUNT_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
      }

        int xmtrs = jtxtfld_XMTRS.getText().length();
         System.out.println(xmtrs);
        if (xmtrs != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_XMTRS.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_XMTRS_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_XMTRS_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
        }

        int rptrs = jtxtfld_RPTRS.getText().length();
         System.out.println(rptrs);
        if (rptrs != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_RPTRS.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_RPTRS_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_RPTRS_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
       }

        int rcvrs = jtxtfld_RCVRS.getText().length();
        System.out.println(rcvrs);
        if (rcvrs != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_RCVRS.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_RCVRS_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_RCVRS_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
         }


        int coll = jtxtfld_COLL.getText().length();
        System.out.println(coll);
        if (coll != 0){
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);
        pst.setString(1, jtxtfld_COLL.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jlbl_COLL_COST.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jtxtfld_COLL_QTY.getText());
        pst.setString(4, null);
        pst.setString(5, newCRM2);
        pst.executeUpdate(addSQL2);
         }


        //conn.commit();



    }catch (SQLException e){}


   }
```

I would like to use the `addBatch()` method, but it doesn't seem to work within Netbeans 8.0.2. I would appreciate it if you could guide me in any way.

Comment: You should be calling `executeUpdate()` with no arguments. As you haven't provided the NPE or shown any code where it is thrown from, you can't be helped with your `addBatch()` problem. And never ignore exceptions.

Comment: In fact it's surprising it works at all, with those unfulfilled ? marks in the SQL. Does it really?

Comment: Well, it does work. There are 5 db entries and 5 "?" -no unfulfilled. What it doesn't do is that it's not efficient. The entries are posted again after the first sweep through into the database. I would like to just have it inserted once.

Comment: So this isn't the real code. And where is the `addBatch()` code you are actually asking about? And the error message you are getting?

Comment: user207421: Thanks for taking the time to review this. The code submitted is the code I am using. Why? Because I couldn't get the addBatch() to work - so I switched it to "executeUpdate" instead. However, it now inserts multiple copies to the database. I want to be able to insert into the db only those lines in my form that have entries. The coding inserts the empty lines also.  I took your advice and removed the arguments from the executeUpdate().

Comment: Exactly. This isn't the real code. The real code follows my advice. The code above does not work. And you ***STILL** haven't provided anything that would let anybody answer your question, despite being asked for it three times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Solved the autobatch() problem. Had two problems. The null exception was because the 
 database wasn't being connected. The second problem was that I had too many repeats 
 of the pst statement. The empty spaces was an issue but I used the length of each 
 first column --if the length was more than zero then the line was added to the 
 database. 

  private void UpdateRecordTablePROPOSALMAT() throws SQLException, ParseException{
          Connection conn ;
          try {

           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:proposaldb");
          newCRM = jtxtfldCRM.getText();
         String  addSQL2 = "INSERT INTO MATERIALTBL (MATLINEITEM, MATLINEITEMCOST, "
         + "MATLINEITEMQTY, MATMOSS, MATCRM)"
         + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement psts = conn.prepareStatement(addSQL2);

        int tubes = String.valueOf(AMT7A).length();

        if(tubes != 0){
        psts.setString(1, String.valueOf(AMT7A));//Couplings Name
        psts.setString(2, String.format("%.2f", AMT8A));//Couplings Cost
        psts.setString(3, String.format("%.2f",AMT9A));//Couplings QTY
        psts.setString(4, null);
        psts.setString(5, newCRM);
        psts.addBatch();
       }

        int coup = String.valueOf(AMT10A).length();

        if(coup != 0){
        psts.setString(1, String.valueOf(AMT10A));//Couplings Name
        psts.setString(2, String.format("%.2f",AMT11A));//Couplings Cost
        psts.setString(3, String.format("%.2f",AMT12A));//Couplings QTY
        psts.setString(4, null);
        psts.setString(5, newCRM);
        psts.addBatch();
       }

        int cmtrs = String.valueOf(AMT13A).length();

        if(cmtrs != 0){

        psts.setString(1, String.valueOf(AMT13A));//Cold Water Meters Name
        psts.setString(2, String.format("%.2f",AMT14A));//Cold Water Meters Cost
        psts.setString(3, String.format("%.2f",AMT15A));//Cold Water Meters QTY
        psts.setString(4, null);
        psts.setString(5, newCRM);
        psts.addBatch();
       }

    [  continue with more addBatch line items ]


          int[] affectedRecords = psts.executeBatch();        

          }finally {
        PreparedStatement psts =null;         
   if(psts != null) {   }
      }
     }
```